# jquery ui autocomplete on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a text-field on which I have kept auto-complete that works like a charm.
Now I want something on same button click, unlike
if something is typed in textbox and on click it shows matched data same like autocomplete, can it be possible?

This is what I have tried, it showed me no error also nothing gets displayed also checked in console.

```
var availableTags = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "value": "hr@test.com",
    "label": "Test HR"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "value": "demo@demo.com",
    "label": "Demo demo"
  }
];
```

My jquery code

```
$( "#search-btn" ).click(function() {
        $( "#domain-field" ).autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
        });
    });
```

My Html code

```
<form id='homepage-form'>
               <div class='input-group'>
                  <input type="text" required="required" placeholder="keywords" id="domain-field" class="form-control input-lg" autofocus="autofocus" autocomplete="off">
                  <span class='input-group-btn'>
                  <button class='orange-btn' data-loading='none' id='search-btn' type='button'>
                  <span class='hidden-xs'>Find email addresses</span>
                  <span class='visible-xs'>Search</span>
                  </button>
                  </span>
               </div>
            </form>
```

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: Jus to be clear, you want to open an input's autocomplete menu when you click on a button?

Comment: yes I want something like that

Answer (score 0):

You could try this.

```
$( "#search-btn" ).click(function() {
    $("#domain-field").data("uiAutocomplete").search($("#domain-field").val());
});
```

This is apparently the way to do it in newer version of jQuery ui.